# Do Equal Angles at the Circumference Subtend Equal Chords?

Tags: geometry, circles

Do Equal Angles at the Circumference Subtend Equal Chords?

This may seem like a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find a definite answer on the internet and none of my textbooks mention this rule. Is this rule correct?

Comment: Yes.  If the angle subtended by an arc at the center of the circle is $\theta$, then the angle subtended by that arc at any point on the circumference (outside that arc) is $\theta/2$.  Just follow the reasoning to the chord.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry for the stupid question

Comment: Not a stupid question at all, I don't think, but it's a classic fact that is useful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that equal angles at circumference subtend equal chords.

However, the explanation should NOT be taken as the chord length is proportional to the angle subtended at circumference.

[image]

In the figure, all green marked angles are equal. Then $\dfrac {L}{2} = r \sin \theta$. After simplification (by treating r as constant), we have $\quad L \quad \alpha \quad  \sin \theta \quad$ .

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you draw those circle diagrams?

Comment: @Nanoputian I am using Geogebra.